# erro de web.xml is missing and <failOnMissingWebXml> is set to true

Tags: eclipse

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Geralmente a pergunta que se faz é, você já fez o deploy no projeto?
A reposta é sim.

cliquei com o direito no projeto fui em Maven depois Update project, é procedimento que sempre faço nós meus projetos e dessa fez está dando problema.

web.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.comercial.adm</groupId>
    <artifactId>ComercialADM</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>



    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>




        <!-- PrimeFaces (biblioteca de componentes) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mojarra (implementacao do JSF) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.21</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <finalName>ComercialADM</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>




</project>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque como o packaging foi setado como war, o maven reconhece por padrão a configuração da necessidade de um web.xml, dado a versão do servlet que você esteja utilizando, caso ela for anterior à versão 3.0, o web.xml é necessário.

Caso a versão for a atual, uma forma de eliminar esse erro, é com o maven-war-plugin, em sua configuração, setar o failOnMissingWebXml como false.

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#failOnMissingWebXml

Answer (score 1):

Talvez seja útil pra mais alguém (5 anos depois da resposta aceita) uma segunda alternativa...

Utilizando a modelVersion 4.0 e servlet 4.0.1 aqui, foi suficiente incluir `<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>` em `<properties>` para o Eclipse não reclamar, sem precisar depender do plugin `maven-war-plugin`.

pom.xml (trecho relevante):

```xml
    <properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <!-- outras properties -->
    </properties>
```